# Signed Borel Measures and Functions of Bounded Variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures, total-variation, signed-measures

Let $\nu$ be a finite signed Borel measure on the closed interval $[a,b]$. We can define a function $F_\nu : [a,b]$ by $$F_\nu(x) = \nu([a,x]).$$It can be shown that $F_\nu$ has bounded variation and is right-continuous. An exercise in my class notes asks to prove that $|\nu|([a,b]) = V(F_\nu, [a,b])$, where the right-hand side denotes the total variation of $F_\nu$. Immediately after this, the notes state the following theorem:

"The map $\nu \mapsto F_\nu$ is a bijection from the set of finite signed Borel measures on $[a,b]$ to the set of functions of bounded variation that take value $0$ at $a$ and that are right-continuous."

My problem is that neither of these statements are true. Both break when we consider the measure $\delta$ given by $$\delta(A) = \begin{cases} 1, &\quad a \in A \\ 0, &\quad a \notin A
\end{cases}.$$

In this case, $F_\delta$ is identically $1$, and so $V(F_\delta,[a,b]) = 0$ while $|\delta|([a,b]) = \delta([a,b]) = 1$. Moreover, $F_\delta$ does not take the value $0$ at $a$, so the second statement is false too.

How do we fix this? Can we just limit ourselves to the meausures $\nu$ for which $\nu(\{a\}) = 0$? Or is there a change we can make so that the results still apply to *all* signed measures?

Comment: Maybe setting $F_\nu(a)=0$ fixes the issue.

Comment: I think this would make bijectivity fail, because then $\delta$ and the zero measure would be sent to the same $F_\nu$.

Comment: Would deleting the "value 0 at $a$" part from the statement and instead saying $|F_\nu(a)|+V(F_\nu,[a,b])=|\nu|([a,b])$ (or some variation of this) work?